# cannot boot Ubuntu after removing packages?

Tags: installation, boot, package-management

I have problem now with booting into Ubuntu because I removed some packages from package manager and its dependencies by mistake.

After I saw desktop removing applications one by one and the theme starting to disappear.

After I tried to restart the login, I tried to fix it using recovery mode but it's not working.

I am sure there are important packages removed, the problem is that I have no backup for my files ..

Also, I need my Firefox stored passwords. I tried to boot to Ubuntu live CD but files encrypted in home folder and no access to it. Is there away to access it ?

---

**Further Information:**

I think can boot, and have boot menu, after choosing boot normal or recovery .. I have some output but don't reach the desktop.

I don't think there is problem with grub boot because I have the boot menu, I think the problem is that important system packages have been removed .. and that maybe the reason that recovery mode didn't do anything , fix dkge didn't help and any other option in the recovery menu.

I think the solution may require the re-installation of Ubuntu, but I am afraid of losing important data like files and Firefox passwords .. etc.

I remember on windows when I was fixing the os I would repair and files application still existed, is that the same on Ubuntu? can i use Ubuntu 12.10 cd and start install it on the same partition and finally I'll find my application and files?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by the following:

> After I tried to restart the login, I tried to fix it usinh recovery mode but it's not working.

Can we please clarify? Do you mean one of the following:

1. You cannot boot. Your boot fails with some kind of output on the screen before anything noticeable happens.
2. You cannot boot. Your boot does not get beyond the purple Ubuntu boot screen.
3. You can boot, but not into the desktop?
4. You can boot, but into the desktop, but there is something wrong with programs that you use , data you once had, or some combination of the two.

If you can boot, but not into the desktop, there's a way to get a terminal without going into the desktop. If greeted with a black screen after booting, where your computer seems to stall, press Shift+Alt+F1 to get the first terminal. Once Ubuntu is started, there are six terminals (F1 - F6). The desktop is always in F7 (Shift+Alt+F7); by default, after booting, Ubuntu starts in the desktop mode.

If you cannot log in, then you might need to fix your partition table or bootloader; you might need to fix something in GRUB.

Since your disk is encrypted, you might have permanent data loss. If you cannot boot into your system, there might not be a computationally feasible way to obtain your encrypted data.

(Did that help, Ayman?)